# Horizontal Blinds: Inside or Outside Mount Type for Windy Weather

Tags: windows, blinds, curtain-rail

I am thinking of buying Horizontal Blinds. I will either buy Inside Mount or Horizontal Outside Mount. I live on an upper floor with very Windy, Blowing weather.

Between the two, what is best option to prevent noise from blind/ banging against wall window reduction when its open? Or does it matter? The fabric material will still be the same.

My last blinds were Vertical blinds, so I know how blinds clanging against window can cause noise. This time I am buying very heavy blinds, and looking at mount options also.

Note: I always keep the windows slightly open, and blinds closed for privacy. My actual windows slide open from right to left.

[image]

Comment: Doubt that it matters.  With window open the wind will move things.  Only thing that might help is if you could raise blinds above the opening of window.

Comment: if I do that, the the blinds might just hit the window frame on inside mount, instead of the walls on outside mount

Comment: I meant if the window opens from the bottom(as in answer below), you can raise the bottom of the blinds to above the open window temporary.

Comment: hi @crip659 thanks, My actual windows slide open from right to left, not sure how the answers below would change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have double hung sash windows like in this picture and you want to open the window on a windy day, just open it at the bottom, and raise the blinds above the level of the opening.

If you have window frames that you find beautiful, that is the reason to get inside mount blinds.  If you have shallow or awkward inside framing, that is the reason to get outside mount blinds.  If you have very small windows, outside framing can produce a nice aesthetic, if that is what you want.

If you want to keep the blinds closed and the window open and avoid flapping, install them inside, and install clips at the bottom of the frame that you can push the bottom bar of the bracket into.  The louvers will still rattle but the entire blind won't flap around if it's clipped in at the bottom.

Alternately replace the windows with ones with blinds built in between the panes. Obviously that will be a much more expensive project.

I think there are also horizontal blinds that run in tracks.  That might solve the problem in a way similar to clips at the bottom, though probably a lot more expensive.

Comment: ok, so to answer the original question, given the two choices, does it matter? just looking for direct answer on the options, thanks !

Comment: by the way, I always keep the windows slightly open, and blinds closed for privacy

Comment: also, My actual windows slide open from right to left

Comment: @mattsmith5 Given the two choices I think inside mount would be worse because the blinds will hit the window pane. Most blinds include "hold down brackets" to keep the blinds from flopping in the breeze and they can be installed for both inside and outside mount.